# Visual Studio - connect to AWS instance via bastion server

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, bastion-host

I am developing some machine learning code and I just got an AWS instance for that. To access the instance, I need to

1. ssh from the local machine to a bastion server (which is also an AWS instance).
2. ssh from the bastion server to the development machine.

For development, I would like to attach Visual Studio to the remote machine. Is there a way for doing that? I tried adding a `~/.ssh/config` file with the login credentials in the bastion server, but that does not change the available hosts listed by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use this plugin and follow this blog:

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks#_proxycommand

For a quick description, it will open a connection to the bastion in the background, and then it will connect to your development instance

Comment: Thanks heaps! All I had to do was to follow the [proxy command](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks#_proxycommand) section :)